# Does $\kappa^\lambda=\kappa$ imply $\mu^\lambda=\mu$ for all $\mu>\kappa$, given $\kappa$, $\mu$, $\lambda$ are cardinals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

This problem is originated from the experience that I was trying to prove 5.19 and 5.20 on Page 60 of Set Theory, Jech(2006).

It seems to be right with **AC**, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: I had just finished writing the answer when you hit delete. But since you found the duplicate I suppose it's better this way. :-)

Comment: Apologies for imposing a deadweight loss on you. I shall be more careful next time.

Comment: No biggie... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not: if $\mu>\kappa$ has cofinality to $\lambda$, then $\mu^\lambda>\mu$ by [König’s theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28set_theory%29#K.C3.B6nig.27s_theorem_and_cofinality) (which does require the axiom of choice).

Comment: @MettaWorldPeace: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 3):

No, not even closely.

Let $\kappa$ be of countable cofinality and $\kappa>\frak c$. We have that ${\frak c}^{\aleph_0}=\frak c$, but $\kappa^{\aleph_0}=\kappa^{\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)}>\kappa$.

Comment: Thank you. As you have told me in another problem, "$\operatorname{cf}{\kappa}$ is not monotone with respect to $\kappa$", I shouldn't expect cardinals behave like that.